# How to change data structure with pandas (unpivot)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Following CSV with sampledata is given:

```
Projectname;Step 1 Start;Step 1 End;Step 2 Start;Step 2 End;Step 3 Start;Step 3 End;…;…;Step 21 Start;Step 21 End
Project A;01.01.2020;02.01.2020;02.01.2020;03.01.2020;03.01.2020;04.01.2020;…;…;21.01.2020;22.01.2020
Project B;01.02.2020;02.02.2020;02.02.2020;03.02.2020;03.02.2020;04.02.2020;…;…;21.02.2020;22.02.2020
Project C;01.03.2020;02.03.2020;02.03.2020;03.03.2020;03.03.2020;04.03.2020;…;…;21.03.2020;22.03.2020
```

Each row represents one project. Each project has 21 steps. For each step is a column with a start timestamp and a column with a end timestamp. In total 42 columns with timestamps.

What I need is a CSV with following structure:

```
Projectname;Stepname;Start;End
Project A;Step 1;01.01.2020;02.01.2020
Project A;Step 2;02.01.2020;03.01.2020
Project A;Step 3;03.01.2020;04.01.2020
Project A;Step 21;21.01.2020;22.01.2020
Project B;Step 1;01.02.2020;02.02.2020
Project B;Step 2;02.02.2020;03.02.2020
Project B;Step 3;03.02.2020;04.02.2020
Project B;Step 21;21.02.2020;22.02.2020
Project C;Step 1;01.03.2020;02.03.2020
Project C;Step 2;02.03.2020;03.03.2020
Project C;Step 3;03.03.2020;04.03.2020
Project C;Step 21;21.03.2020;22.03.2020
```

Each row represents one step with start and end timestamp.
Can I do this data structure transformation with pandas (also other modules are welcome), and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First was replaced order of values in columns names with [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r'(Step \d+)\s+(Start|End)', r'\2_\1')
print (df)
  Projectname Start_Step 1  End_Step 1 Start_Step 2  End_Step 2 Start_Step 3  \
0   Project A   01.01.2020  02.01.2020   02.01.2020  03.01.2020   03.01.2020   
1   Project B   01.02.2020  02.02.2020   02.02.2020  03.02.2020   03.02.2020   
2   Project C   01.03.2020  02.03.2020   02.03.2020  03.03.2020   03.03.2020   

   End_Step 3 Start_Step 21 End_Step 21  
0  04.01.2020    21.01.2020  22.01.2020  
1  04.02.2020    21.02.2020  22.02.2020  
2  04.03.2020    21.03.2020  22.03.2020
```

So is possible use [`wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html):

```
df = pd.wide_to_long(df, 
                     stubnames=['Start','End'], 
                     i='Projectname', 
                     j='Stepname', 
                     sep='_', 
                     suffix='Step \d+').reset_index()
print (df)
   Projectname Stepname       Start         End
0    Project A   Step 1  01.01.2020  02.01.2020
1    Project B   Step 1  01.02.2020  02.02.2020
2    Project C   Step 1  01.03.2020  02.03.2020
3    Project A   Step 2  02.01.2020  03.01.2020
4    Project B   Step 2  02.02.2020  03.02.2020
5    Project C   Step 2  02.03.2020  03.03.2020
6    Project A   Step 3  03.01.2020  04.01.2020
7    Project B   Step 3  03.02.2020  04.02.2020
8    Project C   Step 3  03.03.2020  04.03.2020
9    Project A  Step 21  21.01.2020  22.01.2020
10   Project B  Step 21  21.02.2020  22.02.2020
11   Project C  Step 21  21.03.2020  22.03.2020
```

Comment: Sample works great, thanks so far. Now I try to adapt it to my original data. The columns with "Start", "End" and "Stepname" have been added. But my dataframe now has 45 columns (the old and the new columns) but 0 rows. Any idea what can causes this problem?

Comment: When printing df.head, I get erroromessage: bound method NDFrame.head of Empty DataFrame

Comment: @Jens Error means there are missing `()` after df. head() like df. head

Comment: @Jens I am on phone only now, but problem is not same format of columns names like in question. Is possible share exactly df.columns.tolist() with real data? Tomorrow I can find solution.

Comment: Ok,  I found the column names as origin of my problem. My original names are a bit more complex then in given sample data (I´m sorry that I can´t post the original names. I have to anonymize them). The pattern is like "Start Job (Start)", "Start Job (End)", "Provide Data (and add informations) (Start)", "Provide Data (and add informations) (End)", "Production(and qualitycheck) (Start)", "Production(and qualitycheck) (End)". Changing the names with df.columns.str.replace(r'(.*) \((Start|End).*', r'\2_\1') works fine, but i guess the wide_to_long function is missing any numeric information?

Comment: @Jens - yop, `wide_to_long` need numbers, I use `str.replace` for numbers to end of columns names. So in real data are no numbers?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212772/discussion-between-jens-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 0):

You Can use [pandas wide to long](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html)

Example from documentation:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'famid': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
    'birth': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
    'ht1': [2.8, 2.9, 2.2, 2, 1.8, 1.9, 2.2, 2.3, 2.1],
    'ht2': [3.4, 3.8, 2.9, 3.2, 2.8, 2.4, 3.3, 3.4, 2.9]
})
df


 famid  birth  ht1  ht2
0      1      1  2.8  3.4
1      1      2  2.9  3.8
2      1      3  2.2  2.9
3      2      1  2.0  3.2
4      2      2  1.8  2.8
5      2      3  1.9  2.4
6      3      1  2.2  3.3
7      3      2  2.3  3.4
8      3      3  2.1  2.9


l = pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames='ht', i=['famid', 'birth'], j='age')
l

                  ht
famid birth age
1     1     1    2.8
            2    3.4
      2     1    2.9
            2    3.8
      3     1    2.2
            2    2.9
2     1     1    2.0
            2    3.2
      2     1    1.8
            2    2.8
      3     1    1.9
            2    2.4
3     1     1    2.2
            2    3.3
      2     1    2.3
            2    3.4
      3     1    2.1
            2    2.9
```

Comment: What is OP Data?

Comment: Data from Original Poster